# mysql left join / right join 3 tables

Tags: mysql, left-join, right-join

I have 3 tables in relationship

**1. table privilege (get user privilege from username)**

```
select branch_code,username from privilege where username='joko';
```

Results:

```
| branch_code  | username |
|--------------|----------|
| 'IDJK003MPV' | 'joko'   |
| 'IDJK001MAG' | 'joko'   |
| 'IDJK002MCL' | 'joko'   |
| 'IDBTNCTR'   | 'joko'   |
```

**2. table biodata_karyawan (this table about employees with branch_code)**

```
select branch_code,status_karyawan from biodata_karyawan;
```

Results:

```
| branch_code  | status_karyawan |
|--------------|-----------------|
| 'IDJB001BEC' | 'Aktif'         |
| 'IDJB001BEC' | 'Aktif'         |
| 'IDPA001PPA' | 'Aktif'         |
| 'IDJK001MAG' | 'Aktif'         |
| 'IDJB001BEC' | 'Aktif'         |
| 'IDJB001BEC' | 'Tidak Aktif'   |
| 'IDBTNCTR'   | 'Tidak Aktif'   |
```

**3. table branch**

```
select branch_code,branch_name from branch;
```

Results :

```
| branch_code  | branch_name              |
|--------------|--------------------------|
| 'IDJB001BEC' | 'BEC BANDUNG'            |
| 'IDJK001MAG' | 'MALL ARTHA GADING'      |
| 'IDJK001HO'  | 'HEAD OFFICE'            |
| 'IDPA001PPA' | 'MALL MATAHARI JAYAPURA' |
| 'IDBE001BGK' | 'BENCOOLEN INDAH MALL'   |
| 'IDJK002MPB' | 'METRO PASAR BARU'       |
```

I Hope the results would be like this guys : (records just sample only)

```
| branch_code  | branch_name    | count |
|--------------|----------------|-------|
| 'IDJB001BEC' | 'MALL BANDUNG' | '5'   |
| 'IDJK001MLP' | 'MALL LIPPO'   | '2'   |
| 'IDJK002MPI' | 'MALL PURI'    | '0'   |
| 'IDJB002ZZZ' | 'MALL POSO'    | '0'   |
```

Can anyone can help me ?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you tell us what result do you expect ?

Comment: |branch_code|branch_name|count|

'IDJB001BEC', 'MALL BANDUNG', '5'

'IDJK001MLP', 'MALL LIPPO', '2'

'IDJK002MPI', 'MALL PURI', '0'

'IDJB002ZZZ', 'MALL POSO', '0'

Comment: This is count of what?

Comment: the first sorry for few information, this count get from (biodata_karyawan.status_karyawan)

Comment: your output is confusing. From where do you get this branch name "MALL BANDUNG", "MALL LIPPO"?

Comment: the results of query just sample...

Comment: the key is (biodata_karyawan have branch_code),(branch have branch_code),(privilege have branch_code)...

Comment: please use my schema at this link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/269c3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use count on status_karyawan and then group by

```
select bk.branch_code,b.branch_name,count(bk.status_karyawan) from
  biodata_karyawan bk join
  branch b on bk.branch_code = b.branch_code
  group by bk.branch_code,b.branch_name
```

Here is sql [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8147ac/5)

Updated Query as per your comment

```
select p.branch_code,b.branch_name,count(bk.status_karyawan) from
 biodata_karyawan bk join
 branch b on bk.branch_code = b.branch_code
 join privilege p on b.branch_code = p.branch_code
 Where p.username = 'joko'
 group by p.branch_code,b.branch_name
```

Update [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/269c3/6)

Comment: thanks before Mr. Reva, but how I just show branch_code from privilege where username='joko'  this is my schema guy : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/269c3

Comment: you have relation on privelage table wtith branch table?

Comment: then you want to show branch_code from privelage table or biodata_karyawan table?

Comment: yes.. table privilege have branch_code too..   and I want to show branch_code from privilage(result zero still showing)

Comment: i have added new Query in my answer

Comment: the result in field branch_code only show when record exist, i want branch_code result zero row is still show guys..  because if you query select branch_code from privilege where username='joko'; you will be found 4 branch_code :)

Comment: try this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/269c3/11

Comment: Wow... greats guys.... thanks alot for your quick response and appreciate... my problem have solved. :) this is the update : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/269c3/14

Comment: you are more than welcome. But i would also advice you to google a bit because i think this was not that difficult query. Hope you take my advice in positive manner.

Comment: yes thanks for your cooperation.. :)